# SQL syntax on inner join two table after IN using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having some trouble with the following sql query

```
SELECT c.item1 ,c.id, a.id
FROM table_c as c
WHERE c.id IN
  (
   SELECT id
   FROM table_b
   WHERE someinfo = 'active'
  )
AND c.id IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN table_a as a
ON c.id=a.id
```

The problem lies in the `INNER JOIN`

```
INNER JOIN table_a as a
ON c.id=a.id
```

Sequel Pro outputs

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN
```

Can someone give me some insight on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having tested: the Inner Join should be before the WHERE clause

```
SELECT c.item1 ,c.id, a.id
FROM table_c as c
INNER JOIN table_a as a ON c.id=a.id
WHERE c.id IN
(
   SELECT id
   FROM table_b
   WHERE someinfo = 'active'
)
AND c.id IS NOT NULL
```